# Field placement when editing items in N2 cms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2, n2cms

Working on N2 CMS I'm adding my own content type `Product`. I derive my Product class from `ContentPageBase` and I can add it in the content tree. When I edit an item however, the fields seem to be inverted (`Title` and `Text`). For all example items (e.g. `News`) `Title` always shows up at the top.

**I understand there is a `ContainerName` property which can be set to a *tabname*, however I don't see any property overrides for `Title` or `Text` in the `News` class, so how can this be?**

## Editing news item

[image: Editing news item]

## Editing product

[image: Editing product item]

## Product.cs (custom)

```
using N2;
using N2.Web;
using N2.Details;
using N2.Integrity;

namespace N2.Templates.Mvc.Models.Pages
{
  /// <summary>
  /// This class represents the data transfer object that encapsulates 
  /// the information used by the template.
  /// </summary>
  [PageDefinition("Product")]
  [WithEditableTitle, WithEditableName]
  [RestrictParents(typeof(ProductSection),typeof(ProductCategory))]
  public class Product : ContentPageBase
  {

  }
}
```

## News.cs (default)

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using N2.Definitions;
using N2.Details;
using N2.Integrity;
using N2.Templates.Mvc.Services;
using N2.Web.Mvc;
using N2.Persistence;

namespace N2.Templates.Mvc.Models.Pages
{
    [PageDefinition("News", Description = "A news page.", SortOrder = 155,
        IconUrl = "~/Content/Img/newspaper.png")]
    [RestrictParents(typeof (NewsContainer))]
    public class News : ContentPageBase, ISyndicatable
    {
        public News()
        {
            Visible = false;
            Syndicate = true;
        }

        [EditableTextBox("Introduction", 90, ContainerName = Tabs.Content, TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine, Rows = 4,
            Columns = 80)]
        public virtual string Introduction
        {
            get { return (string) (GetDetail("Introduction") ?? string.Empty); }
            set { SetDetail("Introduction", value, string.Empty); }
        }

        string ISyndicatable.Summary
        {
            get { return Introduction; }
        }

        [Persistable(PersistAs = PropertyPersistenceLocation.Detail)]
        public virtual bool Syndicate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Title and Name editors aren't set on the properties themselves but on the Class.

See the `WithEditableTitle` and `WithEditableName` attributes on your class.

And News class doesn't have to specify them because it inherits from `ContentPageBase` instead of the root `ContentItem` class that your `Product` class is using.  `ContentPageBase` has the Title and Name editors already specified so `News` doesn't have to again.

Comment: You are right, I was specifying them again on Product which made N2 place them below! Thanks!